# Is OPTIONS request forbidden in Azure Search Basic?

Tags: azure, cors, azure-cognitive-search

We have an issue with Azure Search Basic instances. **tl;dr;** is that OPTIONS pre-flight CORS request from browser gets a 403 FORBIDDEN in Search Basic.

We resolved this by temporarily going to a Standard instance.

We tried to create a Free service to test and develop a Search service for an Angular website, and we did so successfully. When we tried to upload the whole data set, it exceeded the quota, so we switched to a Basic tier.

We updated the domain and key for the search, but it started to reply 403 when it was reached with the OPTIONS request, given that it is cross-domain. CORS was properly configured, but we even set it to allow all origins and the result was the same.

If accessed directly via postman, the GET requests were correctly addressed. OPTIONS however returned 403.

We were trying to hotfix an issue, so we spun up an instance of Standard and to our surprise it worked again with the whole data set.
We created three Basic instances while trying to test this in US EAST and all of them resulted in the same response.

Is this disabled due to being preview?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected to work. It was a bug and the fix is now in production. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: The fix has now been deployed in all regions. Give it a shot and let us know if you run into any issues. Thanks!

Comment: I set up Azure Search in West Europe Region and I have only managed top get the CORS feature to work on Standard. It does not seem to have any effect on Basic or Free