# Azure Search and CORS issue with PUT

Tags: cors, azure-cognitive-search

This is a follow-up issue with my first [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844091/azure-search-and-cors-issues). I have successfully deployed my AngularJS web site to Azure and I can get interact with Azure Search using the REST API GET method. Now I am facing the issue with a PUT method. It is complaining that my preflight request does not pass control check. By examining the network traffic, I can see that the browser is doing a OPTIONS request method to Azure Search, and the response code is 404 Not Found.

I noted that someone else had faced this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068668/is-options-request-forbidden-in-azure-search-basic) , and the work around is to use Standard Pricing Tier. I am already on Standard and problem is still there. My Angular Search CORS is already set to "*". And I have tried to modify my client side AngularJS $http code by adding headers options but still not functional.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Update #2 to answer @Bruce Johnston, I guess I could not paste too much code as a comment block so I will put them here.

This is a $http.get that is operational:

```
$http.get("https://mywebsibe/indexes/contact1/docs?api-version=2016-09-01",
              {
                headers: {
                  "Accept": "application/json",
                  "api-key": "xxx"
                },
                params: {
                  //api-version: '2016-09-01',
                  queryType:  "full",
                  search: searchString
                }
              }
              )
```

This is a PUT that is encountering CORS issue:

```
$http.put("https://mywebsite/indexes/contact1/docs?api-version=2017-11-11",
      {
        headers: {
         "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
         "Accept": "application/json",
         "api-key": "xxx"
        },
        data: {
            "value": [
                {
                    "@search.action": "upload",
                    "ContactId": "id1",
                    "FirstName": "New",
                    "LastName": "Guy",
                    "Dob": "1990-01-31",
                    "Gender": "M",
                    "Email": "ng@somewhere.org"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some details on which APIs you're trying to call? Specifically, what's the request URL that returns 404?

Comment: Hi Bruce, I am using the Azure Search REST API that is available when you set up the Azure Search. Since my web site is using AngularJS 1.6, I use the $http service to call it. Here is the working code for the GET method:

Comment: my apologies for the above, I haven't quite figured out how to format code in stackoverflow yet

Comment: @Bruce Johnston, I have updated my post with better code formatting so you can review better. Thx.

Comment: Is the hostname part of the URLs correct? I'd expect to see a .search.windows.net domain name after the hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here that prevent this from working.

Firstly, the hostnames don't appear to be correct. They should be fully-qualified domain names suffixed with `.search.windows.net`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Secondly, the PUT request will not work for three reasons:

1. It returns 404 because the URL is incorrect, assuming you're trying to upload documents to the index. The URL of the Index API is `https://<search-service-name>.search.windows.net/indexes/<index-name>/docs/index`.
2. The Index API is accessed via POST, not PUT.
3. Even if you had the correct URL and HTTP method, the Index API is not supported via CORS. Azure Search only supports query operations via CORS. Administrative operations or operations that modify data are not supported. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index#bkmk_cors).

If your goal is to upload documents to your index from the browser, you'll need to proxy the request somehow. Usually we recommend calling Azure Search from your own web API/middle tier, since that avoids having to send your api-keys to the browser.

Comment: my hostname is masked for this post for security reason. In my actual code, yes, it is fully qualified with .search.windows.net. Secondly, I have tried both POST and PUT, and the result is the same.  Thirdly, I am aware that doing using a middle tier is the recommended way (I noted this as per my first post) however, I found this [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents] that states _You can upload, merge, merge-or-upload, or delete documents from a specified index using HTTP POST..._, so I thought I should try. Thanks.